# How to implement Windows left-to-right-moving loading dots?

Tags: vb.net

I have seen a loading animation for many Windows programs and apps, where a set of 5 dots start coming in to the centre of the screen from off the screen on the left, decelerating at an exponential rate but not stopping, and then move on uniformly right for about half a second, then start accelerating exponentially again and run off the screen on the right.

**Is there a native, inbuilt way of using this in VB.NET?** If not, is there a library or .dll I could use to emulate this effect? And if that's not possible, can anyone give an example of how to use `e.Graphics` or a similar method under the `MyBase.Paint` event to emulate it?

Please comment and ask me if you do not know which loading animation I am referring to. Here's a link to a very bad quality version of it (I don't want to use this one): https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vruzrkf8o3dzuy/294.GIF

Comment: WPF or WinForms?  It sounds like you want the Metro/Modern UI progress bar in indeterminate state (I can't pull up your image here at work).  For WPF, you could use the [mahapps ProgressBar](http://mahapps.com/controls/progressbar.html) - `<metro:MetroProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"/>`.  I don't know what's available for WinForms.

Comment: @Mark I'm using WinForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default ProgressBar doesn't support this for windows forms application.

Try the below code

```
Dim AreaHeight As Integer
Dim AreaWidth As Integer
Dim NumberOfItems As Integer
Dim DistanceBetweenItems As Integer
Dim ItemLength As Integer
Dim ItemX() As Decimal
Dim ItemIndex As Integer
Dim Bmp As Bitmap
Dim G1 As Graphics

Dim Stage As Integer
Dim dx1 As Integer
Dim dx2 As Decimal

Dim PictureBox1 As PictureBox
Dim WithEvents Timer1 As Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Size = New Size(235, 95)
    Me.Text = "ProgressBar"
    Me.Location = New Point(CInt((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) / 2), CInt((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height) / 2))
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow

    PictureBox1 = New PictureBox
    PictureBox1.Size = New Size(175, 15)
    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(20, 20)
    Me.Controls.Add(PictureBox1)

    AreaHeight = PictureBox1.Height
    AreaWidth = PictureBox1.Width
    NumberOfItems = 4
    DistanceBetweenItems = 5
    ItemLength = 6
    ItemIndex = 0

    Stage = 1
    dx1 = 10
    dx2 = CDec(0.4)

    ReDim ItemX(NumberOfItems - 1)
    InitializePositions()

    Bmp = New Bitmap(AreaWidth, AreaHeight)
    G1 = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp)
    PictureBox1.Image = Bmp

    Timer1 = New Timer
    Timer1.Interval = 30
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub AnimateProgressBar()
    G1.Clear(Color.White)

    If ItemIndex >= NumberOfItems Then
        ItemIndex = 0
        Stage += 1

        If Stage = 3 Then
            Stage = 1
            InitializePositions()
        End If
    End If

    Dim Distance As Integer = CInt(((AreaWidth / 2) * Stage) - (ItemLength * (ItemIndex + 1)) - (DistanceBetweenItems * ItemIndex) + (NumberOfItems * (ItemLength + DistanceBetweenItems)))

    If ItemX(ItemIndex) + dx1 > Distance Then
        ItemX(ItemIndex) = Distance
        ItemIndex += 1
    Else
        ItemX(ItemIndex) += dx1
    End If

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To NumberOfItems - 1
        G1.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, ItemX(i), CInt((AreaHeight - ItemLength) / 2), ItemLength, ItemLength)
        G1.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, ItemX(i), CInt((AreaHeight - ItemLength) / 2), ItemLength, ItemLength)
        ItemX(i) += dx2
    Next

    Me.PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializePositions()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To NumberOfItems - 1
        ItemX(i) = -ItemLength * (i + 1) - (DistanceBetweenItems * i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    AnimateProgressBar()
End Sub
```

If you tweak its parameters a little bit I think you will get the desired behavior.